# Odd and Even numbers in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here's code that returns `True` if the list contains an odd number

```
numbers = [10, 5, 24, 8, 6]  
count = 0  
for number in numbers:  
    count += number % 2 == 1  
print(count > 0)
```

---

How can we modify it so it returns `True` if ALL of the numbers are odd?

Comment: `print(count==len(numbers))`

Comment: By the way, printing is not the same thing as returning.

Comment: `all(x % 2 == 1 for x in numbers)`. Sometimes code needs to be replaced, not modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest change to make that work would be changing your last line from

```
print(count > 0)
```

to

```
print(count==len(numbers))
```

However, you could do the whole thing more concisely with a generator expression and the built-in function [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
numbers = [10, 5, 24, 8, 6]  
print(all(n%2 for n in numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is actually this:

```
>>> numbers = [10, 5, 24, 8, 6]
>>> all(x % 2 != 0 for x in numbers)
>>> False
```

---

Now if you want to count all the odd values in a list, all you need is:

```
>>> numbers = [10, 5, 24, 8, 6]
>>> sum(x % 2 != 0 for x in numbers)
>>> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 1
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        count -= 1
print(count > 0)
```

There are many different ways to modify it, but this will print True only if all the numbers are odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy to improve performance:

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.array([11,4,24,8,6])
print(np.all(numbers % 2==1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm also new in this and I use this one as it seems easer to understand ,remmber and use.

```
numbers = [10, 5, 24, 8, 6]
all(x % 2 != 0 for x in numbers)
```

hope this somehow helps , keep up the work and may we success big time in it.